# jQuery - How to check if an element is an array or single

Tags: jquery

jQuery 1.7.1

Sometimes I have an element as an array,

```
<tr><td><input type="hidden" class="p" name="it" value="1"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" class="p" name="it" value="2"/></td></tr>
```

The below jQuery code works,

```
$(".p").each(function(i){
alert($('.p')[i].value);
});
```

Sometime I have that element as a single element

```
<tr><td><input type="hidden" class="p" name="it" value="1"/></td></tr>
```

I want to make sure if the hidden input is an array or a single element before trying to execute the above jQuery code. How can I do that using jQuery?

Comment: May I point you towards: "[How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)"

Comment: @DavidThomas I had a look at that before, but I was looking for a jQuery way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, that code [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/vBaVR/2/) for both one input and two inputs.

But, use the `size` method to check:

```
if ($(".p").size() > 1) {
    $(".p").each(function(i){
        alert($(this).value);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me that the code is correct. I double checked my original code and noticed I had $('.a')[i] instead of $('.a')[i].value. For information, I have many input type hidden array elements like $('.p'), $('.a') etc. and for easier understanding I simplified my question.

Answer (score 4):

You could check the `length` of the set jQuery returns.

```
var p = $('.p');
if ( p.length == 1 )
    // single
else if ( p.length > 1 )
    // set
```

---

But this, I believe, is not your problem. Your jQuery code should not reload `$('.p')` on each iteration. Try this — it'll work with one or multiple matched elements:

```
$(".p").each(function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Hans Engel. Your answer solved my problem. In fact, all other replies are also useful.

Answer (score 1):

The result of a DOM query is always a jQuery object. It cannot be a single element. `$(".p").length` will tell you the number of elements in the returned object, which can be 0 if the query matched no objects.