# Identifying Array Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to know whether an object is array or not?

```
 var x=[];

console.log(typeof x);//output:"object"
alert(x);//output:[object Object]
console.log(x.valueOf())//output:<blank>? what is the reason here?
console.log([].toString()); also outputs <blank>     
Object.prototype.toString.call(x) output:[object Array] how?
```

since console.log([].toString()); outputs :*blank*

**1st:**

why i get blank at 2nd last statement?

**2nd:**

Is there a way to know exactly what an object is: Array or plain Object({}) without the help of their respective methods like x.join() indicates x is an Array,not in this way.

Actually,in jquery selection like $("p") returns  jquery object so if i use

```
console.log(typeof $("p"));//output:"object
```

I just wanted to know the actual Name of the Object.Thats it.Thank u for u help

Comment: Take a look into this other question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In pure JavaScript you can use the following cross browser approach:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Array]") {
    // is plain array
}
```

jQuery has [special method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/) for that:

```
if ($.isArray(x)) {
    // is plain array
}
```

Comment: console.log([].valueOf())//output:<blank>? what is the reason here?

Comment: @Maizere Basically `[].valueOf()` returns `[]`, and doesn't make any sense here.

Comment: @Maizere Glad it helped. FYI, jQuery has also [`$.isPlainObject()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/) for objects check.

Comment: Object.prototype.toString.call(x) output:[object Array] how?

since console.log([].toString()); outputs :blank

Comment: @Maizere Because `Object.prototype.toString` is not the same as `Array.prototype.toString`. The latter simply stringifies array, e.g. `[1,2,3].toString() === "1,2,3"`.

Comment: what will a former do than?

Comment: @Maizere It gets a string that represents array as a JavaScript object. You can read more at [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Using_toString_to_detect_object_type).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `instanceof`. Here's some FireBug testing:

```js
test1 = new Object();
test2 = new Array();
test3 = 123;

console.log(test1 instanceof Array); //false
console.log(test2 instanceof Array); //true
console.log(test3 instanceof Array); //false
```

Comment: Maybe the downvoter would be kind enough to explain why the -1, for the sake of learning :)

Comment: Wasn't me (frankly I don't think this is wrong enough to deserve a downvote), but this fails in multi-DOM environments such as iframes and the like. See [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/) for more.

Comment: It is a simple and clean solution which works in my scenario. Tested on latest version of Chrome and Firefox. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is the invocation of `Object.prototype.toString()` on the target object, which displays the internal `[[Class]]` property name.

```
Object.prototype.toString.call( x ); // [object Array]
```

This has the adventage, that it works on any and every object, regardless of if you're working in a multi *frame / window* environment, which causes problems on using `x instanceof Array`.

---

Newer ES5 implementations, also give you the method `Arrays.isArray()`, which returns `true` or `false`.

```
Array.isArray( x ); // true
```

---

And last but not least, jQuery has its very own `.isArray()` method, which also returns a boolean

```
jQuery.isArray( x ); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( someVar ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    alert( 'Array!' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/

```
if($.isArray(x)){
  alert("isArray");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for something like this:

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( someVar ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    alert( 'Array!' );
}
```

Hope this helps. A little to slow :P

Comment: Yes, this has already been posted two or three times.