# Angularjs : Handle varying json response

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, design-patterns

I am using API from a well known travel company and I am having this problem.

The problem is the response for `roomAvailability`.

Now if certain hotel has only one `Room Type`, it sends it as a `Room` object rather than sending it as an array which otherwise it would send if there were multiple `Room Types`

Now in my template, I have a `ng-repeat` like :

`<div ng-repeat='room in Rooms'>`
 `Do some stuff like room.RoomType`
`</div>`

Now what happens is , when `Room` is not an array , `ng-repeat` fails as it doesn't iterate over the Room `array`.

Now what I can do is have a scope variable `canIterate` and repeat the code in my markup.

But is there a better way so that I can avoid this repeat of code in markup ?

Comment: Could you give us a snippet of both JSON responses when it an array and an object, just snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Check HTTP response before putting it to $scope.Rooms. If response has field RoomType, declare  $scope.Rooms = [response]; otherwise $scope.Rooms = response;

Comment: Agreed. How to check if response is an array -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript