# Check if Object Array and ignore all else

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I have a multiple divs returning an array like this:

```
[{"k":"Model","v":"box"},{"k":"Color","v":"blue"},{"k":"Size","v":"med"},{"k":"Type","v":"good"}]
```

Sometimes, non-array items come back and I want to ignore those.
Could be blank spaces or random un-ordered *blank* lists.
So I only want to process only the arrays that come back leave the rest blank.
How could I check if it is array and ignore the rest?

```
jQuery('.overview').each(function () {
   var $overview = jQuery(this),
       specs = jQuery.parseJSON($overview.html());
   if ( !! specs) {
       $overview.html('<div class="bullet_spec"></div>');
       jQuery.each(specs, function () {
           $overview.children('div').append('<ul class="specs"><li class="label">' + this.k + ' : ' + this.v + '</li></ul>');
       });
   } else { // leave blank?? not sure what to do here
   }
});
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/veGPN/
Thanks

Comment: There is `jQuery.isArray()`...

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: `if( !! specs )`? That's a double negative, why not just `if(specs)`?

Comment: `if (specs && Array.isArray(specs) && specs.length)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`isArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/) function from jQuery:

```
if (jQuery.isArray(specs)) {
   $overview.html('<div class="bullet_spec"></div>');
   jQuery.each(specs, function () {
       $overview.children('div').append('<ul class="specs"><li class="label">' + this.k + ' : ' + this.v + '</li></ul>');
   });
}
```

However, it appears the problem in your fiddle is that some of the elements (`x`) aren't even Json. So it's not that the result isn't an array, it's that it is unable to parse the result at all. You can simply wrap your parsing script with a `try/catch` to handle this gracefully:

```
var $overview = jQuery(this), spec;
try {
    specs = jQuery.parseJSON($overview.html());
} catch(e) {
    return;
}
```

[**Demonstartion**](http://jsfiddle.net/veGPN/1/)

Comment: Thanks, none of these suggestions work in my fiddle so I think I might have deeper problems.

Comment: @SteveAustin The problem in your fiddle is that `x` isn't valid Json. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, That works. I was weary to use try / catch after looking in to it more. I ended up simply testing for `[` and if not there leave empty. `var a = jQuery(this).text(),
           str = a.substr(0, 1),
       if (str.indexOf('[') == -1) {
           jQuery(this).empty();
       }`  This seems to work for my purposes.

Comment: @SteveAustin That still wouldn't guarantee that the string was valid Json (e.g. `[+]` would pass). A `try/catch` is still safer, but yeah, maybe that's sufficient for your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is common and crossbrowser code to check error-free for an array :

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call( someVar ) === '[object Array]' ) {
```