# How to handle string or array of strings in mustache template

Tags: mustache, hogan.js

I have a simple/beginner question for using mustache templating in my app (or Hogan more accurately).
I am using an API which sometimes returns a String and sometimes returns an Array of Strings.

I know could wrap the String in a single-element array, but is there also a way to handle this optionality from the mustache template?

Using normal sections like
`{{#stringOrArray}}
<li>{{.}}</li>
{{/stringOrArray}}`
doesn't print the value if its just a String.

Comment: I always go the single-element array route...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know it is a bit late, but here is what I use:

```
{{#test.length}}
    {{#test}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/test}}
{{/test.length}}

{{^test.length}}
    <li>{{test}}</li>
{{/test.length}}
```

It's like feature detection. The first block of code checks to see if test has a length, if it does, it is an array (yes, I know strings are supposed to have a length property, too, but they don't). It will either output the array (if it is an array), or nothing (if it isn't). The second block prints out the value of test if it has no length (i.e. it is a string or integer etc) This means you can use it on:

```
var data = {
    test: "test1"
}
```

OR

```
var data = {
    test: [ "test1", "test2", "test3" ]
}
```

without having to set a flag for whether it is an array or not. Mustache will output both, but the one you don't need will be blank.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know of a way to do this directly from your object without any helper variables.  Here is something you COULD do prior to passing the data to the template to avoid having to mess with the code that generates the original JSON object.

Let this be your JSON object:

```
var data = {
    test: [ "test1", "test2", "test3" ]
}
```

Let this be your mustache template:

```
{{#isArray}}
    {{#test}} <li>{{.}}</li>{{/test}}
{{/isArray}}

{{^isArray}}
    {{test}}
{{/isArray}}
```

Let this be your code that compiles/calls your mustache template (I'm using document.body.innerHTML because that is how I have the JSFIDDLE example set up):

```
var template = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = Mustache.render(template, data);
```

The above setup will print the following out because `isArray` is undefined, so it will execute the block that negates `isArray` with the `^` symbol (eg, it will treat the data as a string even if it is an array):

```
test1,test2,test3
```

I propose if you do not want to touch the code that is generating the JSON, that you inject some javascript prior to calling `Mustache.render` to set the `isArray` property.  Here is how I would test for the existence of the `pop` method in order to set `isArray` properly before passing the data to the template:

```
if (data.test.pop) { data.isArray = 1; } else { data.isArray = 0; }
var template = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = Mustache.render(template, data);
```

This will properly print out the desired li elements:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

I've put a working example here that exercises both the array and string instances in a data element to show that the solution works:

http://jsfiddle.net/s7Wne/1/

Comment: I didn't love your isArray test, so searched on it and found both http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript ...and they disagree.  Gotta love it.

Comment: @lmsurprenant - I'm just doing a rather dirty check to see if it is an array, you can replace it with whichever more elegant check you desire...  The technique of setting the isArray property so the mustache template can work in your scenario is the important part.