# Using Mustache Template with XML

Tags: templates, mustache

I'm using [JMustache](https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache), but I imagine this question would be the same for all implementations.

I'm using Mustache to Generate an XML file. When a list is empty, I don't want the parent tag to show. When the list is not empty, I want the parent tag to show once. I'm wondering what the Mustache Template should look like.

For example I might have either of the two XML files that need to be generated based on the data input:

```
<class>
    <name>Basketweaving</name>
    <students>
        <student>Joe Smith</student> 
        <student>Sally Smithers</student>
    </students>
</class>
```

or:

```
<class>
    <name>Basketweaving at a bad time</name>
</class>
```

The problem I'm having is if I define my template like this:

```
<class>
   <name>{{className}}</name>
   <students>
    {{#students}}
      <student>{{studentName}}</student>
    {{/students}}
   </students>
<class>
```

Then the empty class still has a students block.

e.g.

```
  <class>
        <name>Basketweaving at a bad time</name>
        <students>
</students>
    </class>
```

And if I move the loop:

```
<class>
   <name>{{className}}</name>
   {{#students}}
   <students>
      <student>{{studentName}}</student>
   </students>
   {{/students}}
<class>
```

I'll end up with Students repeated in the first example:

e.g.

```
<class>
    <name>Basketweaving</name>
    <students>
        <student>Joe Smith</student> 
    </students>
    <students>
        <student>Sally Smithers</student>
    </students>
</class>
```

So, what is the proper way to do the template to get my desired behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer to my own question. With JMustache the template should be something like the following:

```
<class>
   <name>{{className}}</name>
   {{#students}}
   {{#-first}}<students>{{/-first}}
      <student>{{studentName}}</student>
   {{#-last}}</students>{{/-last}}
   {{/students}}
<class>
```

The -first and -last are special flags that are only true the first or last iteration, respectfully, of the loop.

As a result the above code will ONLY output `<students>` while looping through the first entry in the students loop. Likewise `</students>` will only be output during the entry of the students loop.

This means that if students is an empty list, the `<students> </students>` will never be output, however if there is one or more entries the entries will be surrounded by `<students> </students>`.

Comment: can it be used to generate XML attibutes?

Comment: Yes, its really agnostic to the format of the output. It spits out the value where you have the {{VAR}}.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a two case approach:

1. a null or empty list is simply omitted
2. a non-empty list is rendered with its elements

### How to render null or empty lists

Mustache's [Inverted Section](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#Inverted-Sections) could render the "nothing found" case (e.g. an error-message or some alternative elements):

```xml
   {{^students}}
<!-- No students found --->
   {{/students}}
```

Would be rendered to:

```xml
<!-- No students found --->
```

But in your case you want nothing instead:

```xml
{{^students}}{{/students}}
```

### How to render non-empty lists

Mustache's [Non-Empty Lists](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) would list all *students* for **each** with name wrapped inside the `<students></students>` collection.

But you only want the wrapping collection-element `<students>` to appear once for the list. Then you could instead test on the *length or size* property depending of your model being *array or list*:

```xml
{{#students.length}}
    <students>
    {{#students}}
        <student>{{studentName}}</student>
    {{/students}}
    </students>
{{/students.length}}
```

will result in this for example:

```xml
    <students>
        <student>Joe Smith</student> 
        <student>Sally Smithers</student>
    </students>
```

The *length-conditional* was inspired by the current top/accepted answer to similar question:
[How to handle string or array of strings in mustache template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24207782/5730279)

### Putting both cases together

So we add both template-parts inside the outer `class` *root-element* with always present child `name`:

```xml
<class>
   <name>{{className}}</name>
{{#students.length}}
    <students>
    {{#students}}
        <student>{{studentName}}</student>
    {{/students}}
    </students>
{{/students.length}}
{{^students}}{{/students}}
<class>
```

Benefits:

- much cleaner and readable template
- the 2 different cases are separated and communicated explicitly

Comment: I think this is clearer than using `-first` and `-last`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `TemplateEncoder` class from the [HTTP-RPC](https://github.com/HTTP-RPC/HTTP-RPC) project (I'm the author), you can do this:

```xml
<class>
   <name>{{className}}</name>
   {{?students}}
   <students>
      {{#.}}
      <student>{{studentName}}</student>
      {{/.}}
   </students>
   {{/students}}
<class>
```

If "students" exists and is non-empty, the content between the markers will be rendered. Otherwise, it will be ignored.

The "." character is a self-reference - within the "students" block, it refers to the students collection itself.

The "?" isn't "offical" Mustache syntax, but might be an option if JMustache is not a hard requirement.

Comment: What a shift! Then (November 2020) recommending your tool, and recently you wrote about an excellent article about fast _Mustache_ for XML-templating: DZone (January 2021): [Transforming XML with Mustache Templates](https://dzone.com/articles/transforming-xml-with-mustache-templates) ️

Comment: @hc_dev Can you elaborate on your comment? This suggestion is in response to the OP's question about generating XML using a template. The article you mentioned does the opposite - it transforms XML into another representation using a template.

Comment: I perceived OP's question as very JMustache-centric (title, tag, body). So your answer suggesting another dependency seems to me very far from that. But I like you Mustache related article and wanted to encourage you to provide an answer using Mustache. Sorry if my comment was misleading 

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer to clarify the intent.