# Similar methods like Array.IsArray for the other built-in types

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, built-in-types

I'm learning javascript. The book I'm reading told me that instanceOf cannot  identify an Array object when values are passed back and forth between
frames in the same web page because each web page has its
own global context—its own version of built-in types. And therefore ECMAScript 5 introduced Array.isArray(), which we should use. Very clear explanation. My question is why there is no similar methods for the other build-in types (such as Date, RegExp). How can we safely identify them in web page with multiple frames.

Comment: use duck typing to avoid splitting hairs over constructors and worry about needed capabilities.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.prototype.toString`:

```
function typeOf(obj) {
  return {}.toString.call(obj).slice(8,-1);
}

typeOf(obj) == 'Date'
typeOf(obj) == 'RegExp'
...
```