# Test for array of string type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How can I test if a variable is an array of string in TypeScript?  Something like this:

```
function f(): string {
    var a: string[] = ["A", "B", "C"];

    if (typeof a === "string[]")    {
        return "Yes"
    }
    else {
        // returns no as it's 'object'
        return "No"
    }
};
```

TypeScript.io here: http://typescript.io/k0ZiJzso0Qg/2

Edit: I've updated the text to ask for a test for string[]. This was only in the code example previously.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: As TypeScript just compiles to JavaScript, the answers may be found by searching for a JavaScript solution. Further, it's worth it to see some of the answers as the answer depends on the host and how it's being used and passed.

Answer (score 288, accepted):

You cannot test for `string[]` in the general case but you can test for `Array` quite easily the same as in JavaScript https://stackoverflow.com/a/767492/390330 (I prefer `Array.isArray(value)`).

If you specifically want for `string` array you can do something like:

```
if (Array.isArray(value)) {
   var somethingIsNotString = false;
   value.forEach(function(item){
      if(typeof item !== 'string'){
         somethingIsNotString = true;
      }
   })
   if(!somethingIsNotString && value.length > 0){
      console.log('string[]!');
   }
}
```

In case you need to check for an array of a class (not a basic type)

```js
if(items && (items.length > 0) && (items[0] instanceof MyClassName))
```

If you are not sure that all items are same type

```js
items.every(it => it instanceof MyClassName)
```

Comment: `instanceof Array` fails when checking arrays across frames. Prefer `Array.isArray`: https://twitter.com/mgechev/status/1292709820873748480

Comment: @axmrnv Completely agree 

Comment: also, you can break the loop right after telling that somethingIsNotString. With your code, it will necessarily loop through all entire array, which is not necessary.

Comment: @Kukuster value.some() coul be used then, but the answer is related to how to determine array/not-array not about anything else

Answer (score 77):

Another option is [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```
if(! Array.isArray(classNames) ){
    classNames = [classNames]
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't check for the elements being of type `string`.

Comment: Yeap. Then you need one additional checking.

`Array.isArray(classNames) && classNames.every(it => typeof it === 'string')`

Comment: @grigson how about performance when checking 400+ results? Should I disconsider this kind of type check, check just the first child or is it safe tu use this "every" thing?

Comment: @giovannipds Please check [asmironov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50523378/3136474).

Answer (score 43):

Here is the most concise solution so far:

```
function isArrayOfStrings(value: unknown): value is string[] {
   return Array.isArray(value) && value.every(item => typeof item === "string");
}
```

Note that [`value.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) returns `true` for an empty array. To return `false` for an empty array, add [`value.length > 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) to the condition clause:

```
function isNonEmptyArrayOfStrings(value: unknown): value is string[] {
    return Array.isArray(value) && value.length > 0 && value.every(item => typeof item === "string");
}
```

There is no any run-time type information in TypeScript (and there won't be, see [TypeScript Design Goals > Non goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals), 5), so there is no way to get the "type" of elements of an empty array. For non-empty array all you can do is to check the type of its items, one by one.

[Type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) `value is string[]` narrows type of `value` to `string[]` in the corresponding scope. This is a TypeScript feature, the real return type of the function is `boolean`.

Comment: Please note if an Array is empty  you need to check that value.length>0 and not just value.length as this will return 0

Comment: @markyph, 0 is a falsy value in JS/TS and is interpreted as false in this context.

Comment: Yes am aware 0 is falsy -  but the above broke my test as expected it to be "false" but returned 0  - value.length>0 guarantees it to be false

Comment: @markyph That's interesting. Probable due to short-circuit implementation in JS. I imagine it's something like this: for each expression in the `&&` chain, if it's truthy, then go to the next. But if it is falsy, then return it as it is. Return true if all terms in the chain are exhausted.

You can probably use the double exclamation mark convention to coerce a truthy value to a boolean i.e. `!!value.length`. To me that's more readable as it shows intention and it only costs two characters. And it seems in this case it's also more correct. Or arguably the above `value.length>0` is clearer.

Comment: Probably you can also use the "is string[]" as a type predicate. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Answer (score 8):

I know this has been answered, but TypeScript introduced type guards: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards

If you have a type like: `Object[] | string[]` and what to do something conditionally based on what type it is - you can use this type guarding:

```js
function isStringArray(value: any): value is string[] {
  if (value instanceof Array) {
    for (const item of value) {
      if (typeof item !== 'string') {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  }
  return false
}

function join<T>(value: string[] | T[]) {
  if (isStringArray(value)) {
    return value.join(',') // value is string[] here
  } else {
    return value.map((x) => x.toString()).join(',') // value is T[] here
  }
}
```

There is an issue with an empty array being typed as `string[]`, but that might be okay

Comment: The `return false` in the `forEach` has no effect.

Comment: @Ishtar I've corrected it

Comment: it seems to me that you are implementing array.every(it => typeof it === 'string') not in a good way

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
if (value instanceof Array) {
alert('value is Array!');
} else {
alert('Not an array');
}
```

Comment: Rather than copying another answer, please just point out the duplicate as a comment, especially as this doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: This just check the main type not every Array's child.

Answer (score 5):

You can have do it easily using [**`Array.prototype.some()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) as below.

```
const isStringArray = (test: any[]): boolean => {
 return Array.isArray(test) && !test.some((value) => typeof value !== 'string')
}
const myArray = ["A", "B", "C"]
console.log(isStringArray(myArray)) // will be log true if string array
```

I believe this approach is better that others. That is why I am posting this answer.

**Update on  Sebastian Vittersø's comment**

Here you can use [**`Array.prototype.every()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) as well.

```
const isStringArray = (test: any[]): boolean => {
 return Array.isArray(test) && test.every((value) => typeof value === 'string')
}
```

Comment: Instead of using negation in two places here, you could do: `test.every(value => typeof value === 'string')`

Comment: @SebastianVittersø Thanks for the NICE suggestion. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

there is a little problem here because the

```
if (typeof item !== 'string') {
    return false
}
```

will not stop the foreach.
So the function will return true even if the array does contain none string values.

This seems to wok for me:

```
function isStringArray(value: any): value is number[] {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Array]') {
     if (value.length < 1) {
       return false;
     } else {
       return value.every((d: any) => typeof d === 'string');
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Greetings, Hans

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the type-guards (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards), you can do something like ->

```
/**
 * type-guard function to check at run-time if all the elements inside
 * from the array are strings
 * @param array
 * @returns - boolean, true if the array is string array
 */
export function isStringArray(array: unknown[]): array is string[] {
  return array.every((element) => typeof element === 'string')
}
```