# Angular 2 - Check if property is an array

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 how do I check if a property is an array?

I have tried constructor but get a function as below:

```
function Array() { [native code] }
```

My Code:

```
let content: any = {id: '1324234', value:{id:null}};
if(content.value.constructor === 'Array'){
 console.log('It is an array');
} else {
 console.log('Not an array');
}
```

Comment: I guess there is nothing to do with angular2

Comment: well Angular 2 does not have javascript function .isArray()

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
if(content.value instanceof Array){
```

See also [Test for array of string type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130292/test-for-array-of-string-type-in-typescript)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Works.

Comment: Could you please tell how to check this in a template?

Comment: @VikramSingh You can't. You can put this code into a function and call the function from the template (which is usually a bad idea because of performance issues of calling functions from templates). Rather store the result in a variable and bind to this variable from the template.

Comment: but i have dynamic object and i have to display key value pairs in html only if the value is not an Array. I am going with method approach. If you have any better idea please tell me.

Comment: Prepare a data structure that contains the data *and* the result of the type test and use this data structure in the template.