# I have multi type variable as return type. How can I check if variable is having string[] type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
public RowData: PricingOrder[] | Notification[] | ActionLog[] | string[];
```

If `RowData` is `string[]` type (`Ex-RowData = ['cat','dog','anyother'];`)

```
if(RowData === string[] type ){
  //perform some string array related operation
 } else {
  //perform custom class array related operation
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test for array of string type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130292/test-for-array-of-string-type-in-typescript)

Comment: Most trivial implementation using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (or [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)) and [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) would be: `if (RowData.some(item => typeof item === 'string')) { /* string type */ } else { /* other type */ }`

Comment: @MichaelD I dont want to traverse through the content of array. Is there any other trick which the variable type directly?

Comment: @sumit-sharma Is it possible to have such array `[1,"a"]`? combinational of number and string I mean?

Comment: No it will always have string values only in array.

Comment: @sumitsharma: From the attached docs: "_The `some()` method executes the `callbackFn` function once for each element present in the array until it finds the one where `callbackFn` returns a truthy value (a value that becomes true when converted to a Boolean). If such an element is found, `some()` immediately returns `true`._" So accd. to your previous comment the whole array wouldn't be iterated but only the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment your array isn't combinational type. So you just need to check two things:

1. Fist your result is array?
2. Second type of first value of your array.

```js
var srray = ["a","b"];

let isArrayStringType = false;

if(Array.isArray(srray)){
   isArrayStringType = srray.length > 0 && typeof srray[0] == 'string'
}

console.log(isArrayStringType)
```

**Upadte**

Your function's return type does not include `string` type, so you can easily check the second one: `typeof srray[0] == 'string'`

Comment: Why the additional `Array.isArray` check? It isn't one of OP's requirement. You could simply do `typeof srray[0] == 'string'`

Comment: Your right. His function return type does not return `string` too. Thanks

Comment: seems like this is the easiest approach. Thanks a lot