# Property length does not exist on type string | number | {}[]

Tags: typescript

Here is the type of the variable

```
type imageTags: string | number | {
    tag_type: string;
    tag_name: string;
    tag_id: number;
    photo_id: number;
    confidence: number;
}[]
```

This is how i try to access its properties.

```
    if (imageTags.length > 0) {
      return imageTags[0].tag_name === image_type;
    }
```

The variable can be a **string , number or array**  then why am I getting the error **Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string | number | { tag_type: string; tag_name: string; tag_id: number; photo_id: number; confidence: number; }[]'.
Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'.ts(2339)**

Comment: "*The variable can be a string , number or array then why am I getting the error*" numbers don't have a `.length` property. Or as the error message says: "Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'" I don't see what you expect other than somebody re-stating what the error message says.

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting as an answer, but the error clearly states that `number` does not have a property `length`. (I also assume you don't actually want to access `string` like that, too ;) )

Comment: @VLAZ i found the fix to my problem on one of the answers to this questions. However is there a way for me to check if the value is actually an array then access the length property ?

Comment: [How do I check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/767486) | [Test for array of string type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23130292) | [How do you check if a type is an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71623415)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if imageTags's type is Array and only then check the length:

```
if (Array.isArray(imageTags) && imageTags.length) {
  return imageTags[0].tag_name === image_type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`imageTags` is declared as either `string`, `number`, or an array of objects. Maybe you expected it to be an array of `string`, `number` and/or objects instead, so that it's always an array? Then you should use parentheses:

```
type imageTags: (string | number | {
    tag_type: string;
    tag_name: string;
    tag_id: number;
    photo_id: number;
    confidence: number;
})[]
```

Comment: this worked. However is there a more elegant way for me to write the if condition because right now I'm getting an error    => Property 'tag_name' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Comment: You say in the type annotation that you are accepting strings. Then you shouldn't be surprised if you need to deal with strings. I can't tell you how, because I don't know what your code is supposed to do.