# Javascript Object Property Console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, object

I have a javascript object:

```
[{  id: 11,
username: 'me',
firstname: 'my',
lastname: 'name',
}]
```

I'm trying to get the value of the `firstname` property, but I can't seem to do it. I thought I knew how to work with objects until this. I'm developing this within Node.js, which I don't think matters, but I'm new to node, so who knows.

Console.log reads the following for my different attempts:

`console.log(typeof(user_info))` = `object`

`console.log(typeof(user_info[0]))` = `object`

`console.log(user_info)` = `[{  id: 11,
                              username: 'me',
                              firstname: 'my',
                              lastname: 'name',
                          }]`

`console.log(user_info[0].firstname)` = `TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined`

`console.log(user_info[0]['firstname'])` = `TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined`

`console.log(user_info['firstname'])` = `undefinded`

`console.log(user_info.firstname)` = `undefinded`

```
var output = '';
for(var prop in user_info){
    output += prop + ': ' + user_info[prop] + '; ';
}
console.log(output);
```

=

`0:[object Object];`

```
for(var prop in user_info[0]){
    console.log(user_info[0][prop]);
}
```

=

```
11
me
my
name
```

I feel like I'm so close with the last shot, but I can't wrap my mind around how to get the key while using the `for in` loop. What am I missing?

****I'm using Firefox, if that helps. And though I like Chrome, in the current setting, I'm unable to use Chrome***

Comment: no way you can log `user_info[0]` as `object` and have it undefined when try `user_info[0].firstname`. Sounds like you have some asynchronous activity like ajax going on. provide a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Comment: "`console.log(typeof(user_info)) = object`": You can check if something is an array using `user_info instanceof Array` http://stackoverflow.com/a/767492/482489

Comment: `typeof` is an operator (not a function) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof , so it's more correct to use it without the function-call brackets, e.g. `typeof user_info`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var prop in user_info[0]){
    console.log('key = ', prop);
    console.log('value = ', user_info[0][prop]);
}
```

prop - **key** what you need

Comment: This is so strange to me. I can get the 'firstname' to show up if I use this loop, but I can't get anything other than `undefined` if I try to access it directly using `console.log(user_info[0]['firstname']` outside of the loop. Within the loop it logs the firstname four times... Boggled....

Comment: var first_key;
for(var prop in user_info[0]){
    first_key = prop;
    break; 
}
console.log(first_key);

Answer (score 1):

You want key in `for... in`?

How about this...

```
for(var prop in user_info[0]){
    console.log(prop);
}
```

FWIW:
`console.log(user_info[0]['firstname'])` prints `'my'` in chrome.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion in Chrome and I'm still getting the TypeError: blah blah blah... What version are you using of Chrome?

Comment: Trust me, version of chrome has nothing to do with it. Are you sure nothing else is going wrong? Like AJAX calls messing with the variables of interest?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in jsfiddle?