# Display JSON data members with one and more objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have written a JavaScript to display data from JSON object. member ***employeeType*** has two ***employees*** members; one contains an array containing 3 ***employee*** objects, each containing three members and one has 3 members which are "employee", "id" and "email". I am able to display the members if a member has more than one objects but I am unable to display members of an object if the object is alone in employees. I might be unclear to explain it but you can have a look at this [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HASuY/).

My JSON looks like this;

```
var data = {"employeeSearch":{"employeeType":[{"employees":[{"employee":"name1", "id":"1", "email":"name1@company.com"},{"employee":"name2", "id":"2", "email":"name2@company.com"},{"employee":"name3", "id":"3", "email":"name3@company.com"}]},{"employees":{"employee":"name4", "id":"4", "email":"name4@company.com"}}]}};
```

This script display the data

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.employeeSearch.employeeType.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees.length; j++) {
        countItem++;
        output += "<tr><td>"+ countItem +"</td>" + 
                "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees[j].employee + "</td>" + 
                "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees[j].id +"</td>" + 
                "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees[j].email +"</td></tr>";
    }
}
return output;
```

This is how it looks in JsonViews

[image]

Now how can I display the last employee object? Please point me in the right direction and explain what wrong I am doing and what should I do.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HASuY/)

Comment: Your data structure is inconsistent. On time `employees` is an array, the other time it's an object. Make the data consistent. Use an array in both cases and it will work.

Comment: I am using external APIs and this is how they have developed the APIs. I cannot change the data structure.

Comment: because index zero is non existent on the single value employee. you could convert it to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said, if you can, change the data structure so that you have an array in both cases.

If you can't do that and assuming that an employee never has a `length` property, you can simple test for it and then convert it to an array at runtime:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.employeeSearch.employeeType.length; i++) {
    var employees = data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees;
    if (typeof employees.length !== 'number') { // not an array? Make it one.
        employees = [employees];
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < employees.length; j++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This now works fine. But I don't understand this piece of code, "typeof employees.length !== 'number'". Should not it be "typeof employees.length !== 'array'". If it is not an array then make it an array. ??

Comment: No. To find out whether `employees` is an array or not, I see if it has a `length` property (which has a number as value), since arrays have such a property. There are other ways to test whether a value is an array (http://stackoverflow.com/q/767486/218196).

Comment: `employees.length` would be `typeof` `number` since it is a `.length`. He copy the `data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees` to become a new variable `employees`. If `employees.length` is not `typeof` `number`, he put the `employees` into the array bracket to turn it into an array and assign back to the same variable `empolyees` then finally iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the second employees is not an array but an object, it should be an array.

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fish_ball/HASuY/1/

```
var data = {
  "employeeSearch": {
    "employeeType": [{
       "employees":[
          {"employee":"name1", "id":"1", "email":"name1@company.com"},
          {"employee":"name2", "id":"2", "email":"name2@company.com"},
          {"employee":"name3", "id":"3", "email":"name3@company.com"}
        ]},{
        // Notice the differences HERE!
        "employees":[
          {"employee":"name4", "id":"4", "email":"name4@company.com"}
        ]
    }]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now how can I display the last employee object? Please point me in the right direction and explain what wrong I am doing and what should I do.

Like what fish_ball said, your json format is not ordinary.

Your `data.employeeSearch.employeeType[0]` contain an array of objects `empployees` whereas `data.employeeSearch.employeeType[1]` contain a single object `employees`

Any how, you can access the last employee object like below:

```
getEmployees = function() {
    var countItem = 0;

            for (var j = 0; j < data.employeeSearch.employeeType[0].employees.length; j++) {
                countItem++;
                output += "<tr><td>"+ countItem +"</td>" + 
                            "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[0].employees[j].employee + "</td>" + 
                            "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[0].employees[j].id +"</td>" + 
                            "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[0].employees[j].email +"</td></tr>";
            }

                            output += "<tr><td>"+ (++countItem) +"</td>" + 
                            "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[1].employees.employee + "</td>" + 
                            "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[1].employees.id +"</td>" + 
                            "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[1].employees.email +"</td></tr>";


        return output;
    }
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/HASuY/2/)

Like what Felix King pointed out, `empolyeeType` might not always be only 2. If that is the case, then you will need to check the `empolyees.length` or `typeof` and iterate the array if the `empolyees.length` is `>0` or `typeof` is not `number`. See the example below:

```
getEmployees = function() {
var countItem = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < data.employeeSearch.employeeType.length; i++){

    if (data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees.length > 0){

        for (var j = 0; j < data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees.length;j++){
            countItem++;            
            output += "<tr><td>"+ countItem +"</td>" + 
                        "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees[j].employee + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees[j].id +"</td>" + 
                        "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees[j].email +"</td></tr>";
        }

    }else{
                        output += "<tr><td>"+ (countItem+1) +"</td>" + 
                        "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees.employee + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees.id +"</td>" + 
                        "<td>"+ data.employeeSearch.employeeType[i].employees.email +"</td></tr>";
    }

}


    return output;
}
```

[Another JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/HASuY/3/)

Comment: What makes you think that `employeeType` will only ever have two entries?