# Array check followed by forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays, casting, prototype

Now that I'm programming in javascript more and more often, there's a task I'm coming across quite often that I wonder could be dealt with more elegantly.

It's about checking whether a variable, `values` say, is an array of Xs, or rather just an X, immediatly followed by an iteration over it or its elements. 
(X being object, string, number, ... anything really -- except array).

Especially when dealing with xml or json files, a single X is not wrapped in [ ] to make it a 1-element array, and my code breaks if I don't watch out.

I deal with this now in the following way:

```
if (!(values instanceof Array)) values = [values]
values.forEach(function(value){/*do stuff with value*/});
```

For now, I've written a function to take care of this,

```
function arrayIfNot(arr) {return (arr instanceof Array) ? arr : [arr];}
```

Which I can use as

```
arrayIfNot(values).forEach(function(value){/*do stuff with value*/});
```

but as it is such a common task, I'd be surprised if there isn't a common shortcut or library function (jQuery?) to do this.

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

I suppose I could extend the prototypes like so (haven't tried):

```
Array.prototype.toArray = function () {return this;};
String.prototype.toArray = function () {return [this];};
...
```

so that I could do

```
values.toArray().forEach(function(value){/*do stuff with value*/});
```

but I'm always warned against extending the prototype. What do you think?

Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried using `Array.prototype.every()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I've adopted this idiom:

```
[].concat(a)
```

This takes advantage of the behavior of `concat`, which is that if its argument is a scalar, it just adds it to the array; if it is an array, it adds each of its elements.

Comment: Nice.  I'm going to starting using that myself.  :-)

Comment: Nice, very creative! Thanks

Comment: Although, on second thought -- this creates a new object, so that when looping through with `.forEach`, the original elements cannot be changed... right?

Comment: No...if you have `var a = {p: 1}; [].concat(a).forEach(function(v) { v.p = 2; });` will work as you expect, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: If objects, yes, but for primitive values, `var a = 1; [].concat(a).forEach(function(val) {val++;});` gives `a = 1` afterwards.

Comment: Admittedly, so do the `.toArray()` extension of the prototypes, as well as my `arrayIfNot` function.                                                                          I suppose (but can't check right now) that even changing the `arrayIfNot` function to `function arrayIfNot(arr) {arr = (arr instanceof Array) ? arr : [arr]; return arr;}` wouldn't work, because primitive values are passed by value. Therefore, it's necessary to write an assignment, like `values = arrayIfNot(values);` followed by `values.forEach()`. And an 'inline' `arrayIfNot(values).forEach()` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a common way to do this in modern browsers, it's [**`Array.isArray`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), and it's supported from IE9 and up.
MDN has a polyfill for non-supporting browsers.

jQuery has it's own version, [**`jQuery.isArray`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/)

For your specific example, a common way to do it is

```
values = Array.isArray(values) ? values : [values];
```

Comment: But this only determines if the value is an array. It doesn't actually *cast* the value to to an array.

Comment: @Boaz - Nope, you can't really typecast a primitive value to an array in javascript. You could of course create an array, but I don't think that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: The OP is asking about the whole task, IMHO. i.e. - *if a value is not an array, "cast" it as such*.

Comment: @Boaz - I've added something that does that, but it still creates a new array with the value as the first and only index in the array if it's not an array, there's no way to typecast.

Comment: I agree. It might be worthwhile to mention this fact in the answer, since the final solution is not that dissimilar from the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a library, [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) has a lot of fantastic additions to basic JavaScript.  Using Underscore, I commonly do something like this:

```
function myFunction(arg) {
    arrayArg = _.flatten([arg])
}
```

If your `arg` might itself contain arrays which you need to preserve, just add `true` as a second argument to `flatten`.