# Indicate if JSON object is of type Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON object which looks like this:

```
Object {
    @ID: "ID", 
    @Display: "Display", 
    @Order: "Order", 
    List: [
        {
            @ID: "ID", 
            @Name: "Name"
        }, 
        {
            @ID: "ID", 
            @Name: "Name"
        }]
    }
```

What I want to achieve is to return the property name if it is of type array. In the code example above, `List` should be returned. I have tried using `$.isArray(indexOfProperty)` but to no success.
Any help please?

Comment: Your object name/value's look reversed

Comment: That is not a jQuery object. It is a **JavaScript** object.

Comment: According to this link you can check it,[Check Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Keys cannot start with `@`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instanceof` to check if a variable is an array. Try this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] instanceof Array) {
        alert(key + ' is an array!');   
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/orpjexoz/)