# Sails.js how to modify routes to interprate comma separated list of ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, url-routing, policies

According to some JSON API specifciations, such as http://jsonapi.org/format/#urls-individual-resources, the server should interpret a GET request to /myResources/1,2,3,4,5.

Right now the Sails.js router sends this to the `findOne` action.

What is the best way to get this to be handled properly?

I think ideally the router should interpret `/1,2,3,4,5` in the same way it would interpret `?ids[1,2,3,4,5]`, but I realize this may not be trivial.

Another option is to add a policy to all `findOne` requests to check if `req.params('id')` has commas and then reformat the list of ids to a query string and then redirect to `find` (would this work?).  Kind of annoying to add the policy to every controller.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was your suggestion, but its simply a matter placing this in the top of the findone.js blueprint. (or adding this as a policy). Just check to make sure its a string (incase your already passing an array.

```
if(typeof req.params.id === "string"){
    req.params.id = req.params.id.split(',')
}
```

**EDIT**:

For anyone implementing, keep in mind that your `findOne` policies will be applied to this request (see comments).  For example, suppose you have a policy for `find` that applies some parameters to req.options.where to filter records based on the user's permissions.  This won't be applied in this case!

**EDIT**
Unless you just make your routes direct these to the index/find route. You could use blueprints routes for everything else, but those with commas in the "key" portion of the url.

Comment: The problem with this is that then `findOne` has to be able to work as `find` does.  It's not a huge amount of code, but it feels like poor practice.

Comment: A I see what you mean. Then your issues is not so much what find or findOne does, but routing a comma list to a the find blueprint?

Comment: Exactly.  I'm thinking that a policy to redirect might be the best (and it ought to send the request through `find`'s policies as well), and I would also want to fully mask the redirect from the client.

Comment: Instead of a redirect you could just copy the find blueprint into findone custom blueprint folder (with the code above) is the simplest solution and you would get no redirects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It will certainly work, but it feels like kind of a hack.  No offense to you; I think it is the best solution without sails core providing something more elegant.  Another wrinkle that I thought of with this approach is that it undermines policies being assigned correctly; i.e. this request should be picked up by `find` policies, but it will be picked up by `findOne` policies.  For the most part that shouldn't be a big deal, but something to watch out for!

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, that could actually be a serious issue.  See my edit.

Comment: If the solution feels hacky, then its because you need to hack a bit to achieve your hacky urls.  You could easily keep everything as is by using the api as intended with a url such as /myResources?id=1,2,3,4,5,6 or a the following encoded /myResources?where={id : {in:'1,2,3,4,5'}}

Comment: I suppose i should not call your URL hacky as they are spec, but you get what I mean. Their are methods available so as to not hack the code, but you need to change your urls.

Comment: That is ultimately what I did.  FYI, they're not my urls, but from the JSON API spec http://jsonapi.org/format/#urls-individual-resources and I ran into this problem using a client side library  that expects this by default

Comment: Use `req.params.id.constructor === String` instead. It is the fastest and will accurately give you the type. `typeof` will call an Array an Object. `.constructor` will call an Array an Array. Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript/26633883#26633883 as it has a explanation and link to jsperf.com so you can do the test.