# Sails.js/Waterline POST a comma-separated list to create multiple associations

Tags: rest, sails.js, waterline

Following the typical sails.js association example, assume you have a model *User* and a model *Pets*. A user has multiple pets, a pet has one owner - the user. Here are the model definitions for this example for reference: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoMany.md

With Sails.js/Blueprint default RESTful routes, I can hit the endpoints:

`GET /user/:id/pets` - to return an array of a user's pets.
`POST /user/:id/pets/:id` - to create an association between a pet and a user.

Is there any way that I could POST the ids of multiple pets in order to create multiple associations?

For example: Say there are three existing pets with ids `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, and a user with id `u1`. I want to hit the endpoint:
`POST /user/u1/pets/p1,p2,p3` to create three associations (u1<->p1), (u1<->p2), (u1<->p3).

I've thought about implementing this as a middleware that would look for POST requests with comma-separated strings, but I'm not sure how I can generically split one POST request into multiple equivalent POST requests. By "generically" I mean that I don't want to write middleware for every combination of model associations in my app.

This is a related question trying to do almost the exact opposite, but I wasn't able to draw any specific conclusions from it: [Sails.js how to modify routes to interprate comma separated list of ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071545/sails-js-how-to-modify-routes-to-interprate-comma-separated-list-of-ids)