# Checking if object is Array in Parse.com CloudCode

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have this code running on Parse.com CloudCode

```
queryContact.find().then(function(results) {

    console.log(typeof results); // object

    if (results.constructor !== Array) {

        response.success("Found zero results");

    } else {

        console.log("WHY DID IT GO THROUGH!!!");
    }

}).then...
```

The `find()` function normally returns an array, but in my test case it returns 0 results. By logging to console I managed to see that in this case results is a `typeof` `object`. I want to proceed with `else` case only if `results` is `typeof` `Array`. However, my checks fail to capture this, and the code keeps falling through into the `else` section. None of the checks from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript) work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: People need to stop answering this question and voting to close it instead

Comment: Thanks for you diligence George, but I have quoted the same SO question in my question - see bottom. Hence my question here. I was hoping someone here would have experience with Parse's find() function and CloudCode in case they cause some specific behaviours

Comment: Please name your question better then, if it's not generally about "Checking if object is Array" -- that ground has been covered umpteen times before

Comment: Thanks, I've done that now. I'd appreciate if you removed the suggestion to close it

Comment: Are you sure `results` can really be an array, and not only array-like object? If it's an array, the answers in the other question should work.

Comment: The documentation says the output is a list https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check an object is array

```
 Object.prototype.toString.call(results) === '[object Array]'
```

Comment: I just tested it, it doesn't work... The else statements is still getting called.

Comment: @artooras Here's a question: is `results` *really* an array? Or is it an array-like object?

Comment: Good question - the documentation for this function specifies return value as list https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#find - I assumed it's an array because that's what I get through Parse's iOS API

Comment: Try `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(results))` and see what that outputs

Comment: can you tell me what is the output of `Object.prototype.toString.call(results)`?

Comment: The console output is `[object Array]`

Comment: The console output is `[object Array]`, which makes your equation correct. I see the flaw in my original if statement as I was mislead by the result of `console.log(typeof results);` being `object` - the output is always an Array, even when there are 0 results

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using

```
if (results.length === 0) {
```

Somehow this just worked for me.

Comment: This is the correct answer for this question, because Parse.com always returns the results array; all you have to do is check its length.

Comment: You may be right, but it's still strange the the returned array does not respond / allow itself to be identified as an Array. The documentation states the the method returns a list, not array. Can this be the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 if( Object.prototype.toString.call( someVar ) === '[object Array]' ) {
   alert( 'Array!' );
 }else{
   alert( 'object!' );
 }
```

Comment: I just tested it, it doesn't work... The else statements is still getting called.

Comment: Oh, I see. json response is not relevant as it contains a crash error that relates to code happening later in the else case, and which would be prevented if I can stop the else case to run altogether

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to return the names of JavaScript types:

```
function toType(x) {
  return ({}).toString.call(x).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}

toType([]); // array
toType({}); // object
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jv9yn158/)