# Is instanceof Array better than isArray in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, instanceof

From those two posts:

- [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)
- [Check if object is array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array)

There are several ways to check if one object is an array

1. `variable instanceof Array`
2. `Array.isArray(variable)`

I was told that the second method is better than the first one. Is anyone can tell the reason of it?

Comment: the 2nd one is not available in older browsers, but where it is available, hits Arrays from iframes that instanceOf misses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No.** There are some cases where `obj instanceof Array` can be false, even if `obj` is an `Array`.

> You do have to be careful with instanceof in some edge cases, though,
> particularly if you're writing a library and so have less control /
> knowledge of the environment in which it will be running. The issue is
> that if you're working in a multiple-window environment (frames,
> iframes), you might receive a Date d (for instance) from another
> window, in which case d instanceof Date will be false — because d's
> prototype is the Date.prototype in the other window, not the
> Date.prototype in the window where your code is running. And in most
> cases you don't care, you just want to know whether it has all the
> Date stuff on it so you can use it.

Source: [Nifty Snippets](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html#instanceof)

This example, applies to array objects too and so on.

And the standard method suggest by ECMAScript standards to find the class of an `Object` is to use the `toString` method from `Object.prototype` and `isArray(variable)` uses it internally.