# How can I destroy the object created in this constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

So I'm making a JavaScript class that will be transferable with my Java one. It's all done but I want to make sure the right data type gets entered for the arguments.

For example, my Constructor:

```
function Table(header) {
    if (!Object.prototype.toString.call(header) === '[object Array]') {
        throw 'headers not array';
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
        if (!typeof(header[i]) == 'string') {
            throw 'headers['+i+'] not string';
            return;
        }
    }
    this.header = header;
    this.rows = [];
}
```

When you create a new `Table` object, you have to pass in an array. Though you can pass in anything here and the object still gets created, just without the `header` and `rows` fields.

How can I destroy the object? The errors I've tried to throw don't do anything.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but you can do `header instanceof Array` to check if it is an array.

Comment: Why do you need to "destroy" it?

Comment: Javascript uses automatic garbage collection, you don't have to destroy objects by hand. When you stop referring to the object, it will eventually go away.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think the intent is to cause the creation to fail if the correct parameter isn't passed in.

Comment: @DaveNewton if an array isn't passed in, the object is useless. If I can throw an error, it's better than the person using this twiddling their thumbs trying to work out what went wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by the "errors you've tried to throw don't do anything"? I mean, GC "just happens" in JS, and destroying the object from within itself seems contradictory.

Comment: When you throw the exception, the object will be destroyed.

Comment: If you're going to throw exceptions, you might as well throw `Error` objects: `throw new Error("whatever");`

Comment: @DaveNewton I mean, if I run `var a = new Table('not an array');`, no errors are thrown and an invalid object is created.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @Spedwards Well... the way you've written it is broken; check your first logical condition in the console, and consider operator precedence, and consider something like `!==` instead. We have great JS development tools, like debuggers, the console, even simple console logging--might as well use them.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 errors in your code.

1)

```
!Object.prototype.toString.call(header) === '[object Array]'
```

`!Object.prototype.toString.call(header)` returns a boolean, so it's never going to equate to `[object Array]`. This should be:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(header) !== '[object Array]'
```

2)

```
!typeof(header[i]) == 'string'
```

the same as above. This should be:

```
typeof header[i] !== 'string'
```

**The object won't get created if the errors are thrown.**

Comment: I ended up fixing these. It was from old recycled code from 2 years ago. They worked for what I was doing then.

Answer (score 0):

Your first logic statement isn't doing what you think it is:

```
if (!Object.prototype.toString.call(header) === '[object Array]') {
```

The `!` is operating on the call results, not the entire expression. Either:

```
if (!(Object.prototype.toString.call(header) === '[object Array]')) {
```

or

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(header) !== '[object Array]') {
```

will work much better. (Same with your second expression.)

Personally I'd lean towards the latter.

(Actually, I'd lean towards encapsulating this check in a separate method or methods, to make it easier to test, and to make the ctor more communicative.)

Comment: The former is what I had in my old code. When I re-wrote the code looking at the old one, I left out the brackets. I ended up changing to the latter not long before I checked for answers.