# Why, if `$q.all` is not returned an array of promises, is an exception not thrown?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

And on top of this, why are `$scope` values set BEFORE `$q.all` is called completely ignored?

Function within main controller:

```
$scope.apply = function (security) {

    var entity = shareDataService.getModalEntity();
    var depot = shareDataService.getModalDepot();
    $scope.loaded = false;
    var myDataPromise;

    if (entity == "NULL") {
        myDataPromise = getDataService.getDataFromREST(security);
    } else {
        myDataPromise = $q.all(getDataService.keepICorrect(security));
    };
    myDataPromise.then(function () {


                 //DO STUFF


}, function errorCallback(response) {

                    //DO MORE STUFF

    });
}
```

And my `keepICorrect()` function in my service (which is a closure):

```
 keepICorrect: function (security) {

        var promises = [];
            for (var i = 0 ; i < entity.length; i++) {
                promises.push(this.getDataFromREST(security, i));
            }
         return promises;
    },
```

However when the `$scope.apply()` function is executed, nothing happens.  Boolean `$scope.loaded` does not activate on the scope and no exception is thrown (which is what I was expecting).  Why is this?

I've edited the code and made my controller function `Apply` check if `entity = "NULL"`, and this seems to have solved the issue of whether it is an array or not.  Still doesn't answer my question as to why if `q.all` is not returned an array of promises, does nothing happen in the function it is called in, even if before `q.all` is called.

Comment: What is `entity` in that `keepICorrect()` function? The parameter is `security`, and `security` is used in the loop.

Comment: `entity` is an array which is declared and fetched in the service.  `security` is passed through to my `getDataFromREST()` function within my for loop.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return $q.all` ?

Comment: Within my `$scope.apply` ?  I wasn't aware of this, but it makes no difference (i just tried).

Comment: `if (entity === Array)` compares `entity` to the global `Array` constructor function. It doesn't test to see if `entity` is an array.

Comment: `if(entity.constructor === Array)`  makes no difference.

Comment: This surely IS how you check if a var is an array... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding when you would expect an exception to be thrown. First of all, what value does `entity` hold (depending on that $q.all() might never be called...)? Also, where do you throw an error (in `getDataFromREST`?) and could we see the potentially error-throwing code part? Also, you say you `check if entity = "NULL"` but using `=` is not a comparison, but an assignment. Please clarify.

Comment: As above.. entity is an array of numbers which is declared and fetched in the service.  I edited my code to compare and not assign `"NULL"`.  My thoughts were that if an array of promises were not returned to `q.all` why is that not considered an error callback?  But that's besides the point, because if an array of promises isn't returned to `q.all`, nothing within `apply` function is executed, not even the boolean which is assigned before it.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that the Promise library wraps all errors thrown in enclosed brackets code, so you are really recommended to test your functions before wrapping them in a promise mechanism.

In your case:

```
keepICorrect: function (security) {

        var promises = [];
            for (var i = 0 ; i < entity.length; i++) {
                promises.push(this.getDataFromREST(security, i));
            }
         return promises;
    },
```

you say that it is a closure, so I figure that `this.getDataFromREST` should be `undefined`. Please try to add correct code progressively in order to do not have your errors hidden and remove the error in your code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are you implying I am hiding incorrect code?  `this.getDataFromREST` is not undefined, the values are passed correctly.

Comment: I mean that I run your situation a couple times. In both times I could not read any error on my console because the Promise library wraps any runtime error in a sort of `catchAll {}` logic. About the error I supposed to be: in code you posted it seemed it would be better to call `getDataFromREST` instead of `this.getDataFromREST`.