# In Javascript how do I detect different kinds of elements in an array containing sub arrays and single elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am being given data in an array that contains sub arrays and single elements. 
I do not know how many elements in the main array are sub arrays, or how many are single elements, or how many elements will be in a sub array, or where the sub arrays will be in the main array.

Is there a way I can detect the sub arrays or the single elements?

Example:

```
array[ [1,2,3], 4, 5]
```

Comment: Bartek: OK - Can you please give me a code example of how I could detect the sub array using that other question with answers?

Comment: Loop through the array?

Comment: I tried that. But, when I use array[0] I get 1. I thought I would get that sub array. But, I only get 1. Don't I have to use array[0][0] to get 1 ?

Comment: This one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/767496/295783

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop and check:

```
[1,2,[4,5],3].forEach((item, i) => {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        console.log(`Item ${i} is an array!`); // Item 2 is an array!
    }
})
```

Or map to booleans:

```
[1,2,[4,5],3].map(Array.isArray); // [false, false, true, false]
```

Comment: provided you don't need to support legacy javascript engines (really old browsers), this is the correct answer.  If you _do_ need to support legacy browsers, add this polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator `typeof`.

```
typeof 1; //number
typeof 'hola'; //string
```

Although you keep warning in that `typeof array` is `object`. So you need check the class using `instanceof` method (or the static method `Array.isArray(your_variable)`). For this issue you can read this question ([How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)).

In your particular case

```
[1, 2, 3, ['a','b']].forEach(function(element){
    if(typeof(element) === 'number'){
       //todo
    }elseif(typeof(element) === 'string'){
      //todo
    }elseif(Array.isArray(element){
        //todo array element
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `instanceof`:

```
 for(var i=0;i<your_array.length;i++){
        if(your_array[i] instanceof Array){
               console.log("Subarray!");
        }else{
               console.log("Not Subarray!");
        }
 }
```