# Functional js - cant recursively call own function

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming

I am having trouble with getting an incorrect value from an array flatten function when using functional programming principals to generate the flatten function from a generic reduce function. I believe that this is because there is an issue with the recursion within the call, but am unsure how to move past it as the function signatures for both the working and non working function should be the same.

Thanks for any help.

```js
var data = [['one','two','three'], ['four', 'five', ['six']], 'seven', ['eight', 'nine']];

// here is an example of flatten that works perfectly. it takes an array and reduces 
// the internal arrays to a single flat array
function flatten( arr ){
  return arr.reduce(function( ret, curr ){
    if( Array.isArray( curr ) ){
      ret = ret.concat( flatten( curr ) );
    } else {
      ret.push( curr );
    }
    return ret;
  }, []);
}

// here is what I am trying to achieve. This one combines my reduction functon with the 
// functional `reduceWith` function. The code signature is exactly the same, however the
// end result is different.
// `functionalFlatten` does resolve to the correct function inside
var functionalFlatten = reduceWith(function( ret, curr ){
  if( Array.isArray( curr ) ){
    ret = ret.concat( functionalFlatten( curr ) );
  } else {
    ret.push( curr );
  }
  return ret;
}, []);

// this function will return a functional reduction function 
function reduceWith( fn, initial ) {
  return function _reduceWith( arr ) {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arr, fn, initial || []);
  }
}

console.log('data', data);
console.log('functionalFlatten', functionalFlatten );
console.log('normal', flatten( data ));
console.log('fuctional', functionalFlatten( data ));
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked out [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.0/index.html)?

Comment: Nah never seen that library. will check it out. thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code. This works:

```
var data = [
  ['one','two','three'],
  ['four', 'five', ['six']],
  'seven',
  ['eight', 'nine']
]

function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(ret, curr) {
    return ret.concat(Array.isArray(curr) ? flatten(curr) : [curr])
  }, [])
}

var functionalFlatten = reduceWith(function(ret, curr) {
  return Array.prototype.concat.call(ret, Array.isArray(curr) ? functionalFlatten(curr) : [curr])
}, [])

// I assume you want to use .call to keep it functional or what ever
// But I would just do it like this:
var _functionalFlatten = reduceWith(function(ret, curr) {
  return ret.concat(ret, Array.isArray(curr) ? functionalFlatten(curr) : [curr])
}, [])

function reduceWith(fn, initial) {
  return (function (arr) {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arr, fn, initial) 
  })
}

// Again, keep it simple...
function _reduceWith(fn, initial) {
  return (function (arr) {
    return arr.reduce(fn, initial)
  })
}

// You had this...
function reduceWith( fn, initial ) {
  // You don't need to name this function:
  return function _reduceWith( arr ) {
    // Let's keep this in line original function, so remove the default:
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arr, fn, initial || []);
  }
}

console.log('data', data)
console.log('functionalFlatten', functionalFlatten)
console.log('normal', flatten(data))
console.log('fuctional', functionalFlatten(data))
```

Now to the actual problem...

```
var functionalFlatten = reduceWith(function( ret, curr ){
  if( Array.isArray( curr ) ){
    ret = ret.concat( functionalFlatten( curr ) );
  } else {
    // This is your culprit:
    ret.push( curr ); // push will mutate ret
  }
  return ret;
}, []);
```

- `reduceWith` only gets called once (when `functionalFlatten` is defined).
- The inner function will get called every time
- ... but `ret.push(curr)` has the potential to mutate `initial`

Here is proof...

```
function reduceWithMutationSafe(fn, initial) {
  return (function (arr) {
    // Clone initial, so that the original can't be mutated:
    var clonedInitial = eval(JSON.stringify(initial))
    return arr.reduce(fn, clonedInitial)
  })
}

var functionalFlatten = reduceWithMutationSafe(function(ret, curr) {
  if(Array.isArray(curr)) {
    ret = ret.concat(functionalFlatten(curr))
  } else {
    ret.push(curr)
  }
  return ret
}, [])
```

This will work, even though `functionalFlatten` is exactly the same as before
`ret.push(curr)` will mutate the cloned `initial`, but the original one
won't be touched.

But this last piece of code is just proof. There should be no need to use `reduceWithMutationSafe`.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to go through the code and pointing out the areas it can be improved.

Comment: Once again thanks @Arnar. The explanation and the proof you have provided makes perfect sense.

Comment: I would also recommend another way of checking if a variable is an `array`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I fixed your function

```
var functionalFlatten = reduceWith(function f( ret, curr ){
  if( Array.isArray( curr ) ){
    ret = ret.concat( reduceWith(f, [])( curr ) );
  } else {
    ret.push( curr );
  }
  return ret;
}, []);
```

The problem with your initial code was the use of the same `initial` value  for both the parent call and the recursive one which made `ret` to concatenate with itself.

Comment: I don't know why you've been downvoted, but I upvoted to balance back--this is a good answer. To OP, its even more evident if you insert a non-empty array in as the `initial` argument to `functionalFlatten`, you can see that `functionalFlatten` is being invoked each time it encounters a new array, hence the duplication pattern in your result.

Comment: @stefan thanks for your answer. The thing I am unsure of is that the `functionalFlatten` should be created an compile time and should be and is available to the inner function. I didn't reference the function as you suggested for that reason. Also looking at this it seems less efficient as you are declaring a new flatten with each level of recursion not reusing the same function.

Comment: @Stefan: That's not the root of the problem. `reduceWith` only gets called once (when `functionalFlatten` is defined). The inner function will get called every time, but `ret.push(curr)` has the potential to mutate `initial`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can write `reduceWith` as a curried function which gives you better re-use of the overall function.

```
// ES6
const reduce = f => y => xs => xs.reduce (f, y);
```

Now we can write `flatten` as a partially applied `reduce` function

```
const flatten = reduce ((y,x) => y.concat (isArray (x) ? flatten (x) : x)) ([]);
```

That little `isArray` helper is just

```
const isArray = Array.isArray;
```

And it just works. No mutation via `.push`, no `Function.prototype.call`. Just folding and concat'ing.

```
console.log (flatten ([1,2,[3,4,[],6,[7,8,9]]]));
//=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

---

Here's the ES5

```
// ES5
"use strict";

var reduce = function reduce(f) {
  return function (y) {
    return function (xs) {
      return xs.reduce(f, y);
    };
  };
};

var isArray = Array.isArray;

var flatten = reduce(function (y, x) {
  return y.concat(isArray(x) ? flatten(x) : x);
})([]);

console.log(flatten([1, 2, [3, 4, [], 6, [7, 8, 9]]]));
//=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: He Naomik, thanks for your reply. the only thing I'm not sure about is not using `Array.prototype.reduce.call` I do that so any array like object can be passed in and reduced / mapped / filtered etc.. It may be overthinking it though.

Comment: @synthet1c: Can you name an example of when `foo.reduce` would not work and `Array.prototype.reduce.call` would?

Comment: when you use an array like object eg, arguments ```var arrayLike = {
      0: 'zero'
      , 1: 'one'
      , 2: 'two'
      , 3: 'three'
      , length: 4
    };
    someReductionFunction( arrayLike );``` if your using an array like object as long as it has numerical indexed keys and a length property you can borrow methods from `Array.prototype`

Comment: @synthet1c instead of writing all of your functions to support multiple datatypes, I would make a function to convert one to another: `toArray(arrayLike) //=> [...]`. `arguments` is the most common array-like I encounter in JavaScript and that's going away in ES6 thanks to [rest parameters](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#default-rest-spread). `function foo (...xs) { doSomething(xs); }` instead of `function foo() { doSomething(arguments); }` I never liked the implicit behaviour of `arguments` and I'm happy this change is around the corner.

Comment: @naomik thanks for following up. I think you have presented a win win. Less code and it's cleaner. I like it. Yeah I'm really looking forward to `...rest` instead of `slice(args[, startIndex ])`, and the rest of the sugar es6+ will provide.