# local array variable is not an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is this line of javascript not creating an instance of the array prototype? (The var I am interested in is formatSet)

```
var date = angular.copy(srcDate),
    d = '',
    yyyy = date.getFullYear() - 2,
    MM = date.getMonth() + 1,
    dd = date.getDate(),
    hh = date.getHours(),
    mm = date.getMinutes(),
    ss = date.getSeconds(),
    formatSet = [MM, dd, hh, mm, ss];
```

Forgive me if this is a duplicate, but the search terms are a little vague and everything I'm finding illustrates the use of Array.prototype.isArray(), with which I am familiar and still doesn't answer the question.

Also, in case I'm missing something, the scenario that arises are errors: `formatSet.isArray and formatSet.forEach is not a function`.

Comment: I don't know `isArray()` but from a bit of reading it looks to not be broadly implemented.  If I use your above code and change the first line to `var date = new Date(),` then formatSet is an array and has the other expected functions available (forEach, for example).  So, what's the date variable after you run that line of code?

Comment: Okay - after that change this also works...  `Array.isArray(formatSet);` - returns true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do:

```
Array.isArray(formatSet);
```

Instead of:

```
formatSet.isArray();
```

Comment: Derp! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check if is array is like this:

`if (formatSet.constructor === Array )`

This is the fastest method.

`Array.isArray()` doesn’t always benchmark well.

check this for more details:

[How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)