# Function to extract numbers only from a string

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, nan, ternary-operator

I have written a function that I want to take in a string and then return a string that contains only the number characters from the original string. It

```
function pureNumbers() {
      var result;
      for (var i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length; i++) {
         if (Number(phoneNumber[i]) !== NaN) {
            result ? result = result + phoneNumber[i] : result = phoneNumber[i]
         }
      }
      return result;
   }

pureNumbers('(123) 456-7890')
```

Desired result:

```
result: '1234567890'
```

What I actually get is:

```
result: 'undefined(123) 456-7890'
```

I know there's two issues here (possibly more).

1. The `undefined` at the beginning of my `result` is because my function is attempting to return the value of result in the first loop's iteration, before anything has been assigned to it. I set up the ternary conditional to cover this, not sure why it's not working...
2. My first `if()` conditional is intended to make the given character of the string be added to `result` **only** if it is a **number**, yet every single character is being added.

Any help appreciated - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This gets all the numbers from a string as an array, then .join("") to join together the strings with no delimiter between them, I.e., a consecutive concatenation string of digit matches.

```
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;

'something102asdfkj1948948'.match( numberPattern ).join("");
```

Yields "1021948948"

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic is below:

```
var x = 'Hello please call (727) 902-1112';

var numbers = x.match(/[0-9]/g).join('');

console.log(numbers);
```

Result: `7279021112`

Now as to a function, I think this might help you:

```
var x = 'Hello please call';
var y = 'Hello please call (727) 902-1112';

    function pureNumbers(param) {
        result =  param.match(/[0-9]/g);

        if (Array.isArray(result)) {
            return result.join('');
        }
        return false;
    }

console.log(pureNumbers(x)); // returns false
console.log(pureNumbers(y)); // returns 7279021112
```

**Note: isArray() does not work in older versions of IE 9. You would have to do it [differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript).**

Answer (score 0):

Your can also try the following: `string.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');` **OR** `string.replace(/\D/g,'');` to strip all the non-digit characters.

```
function pureNumbers(str) { 
    var num = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
    return num; 
}

alert(pureNumbers('(123) 456-7890'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I only changed your function a little bit, though it can be solved in many ways, especially with regex.

```
function pureNumbers(phoneNumber) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length; i++) {
     if (!isNaN(phoneNumber[i]) && phoneNumber[i].trim() !== '') {
        result += phoneNumber[i];
     }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Hope you may get some hint and improve for better solution.