# Object in function is undefined js

Tags: javascript, function, object, undefined

I am trying to find out whether an object of my Object-Array `CoilArray` contains a certain value.

For this I am using the function `hasValue`

I want to be able to filter on two values and give back a filtered array, as you can see in the function `filterArray`

I have a problem in function `hasValue`.

The error message I am getting says:

> obj is undefined

`obj` is obviously supposed to be the object that I am giving to the function.

Why is it undefined?
How can I define it?

`hasValue` itself seems to be working though

```
var CoilArray = [{
  id: "First Coil",
  systemId: ["System A", "System C"],
  fieldStr: ["Str A", "Str B"],
}, {
  id: "Second Coil",
  systemId: "System B",
  fieldStr: ["Str B", "Str C"],
}, {
  id: "Third Coil",
  systemId: "System C",
  fieldStr: "Str C",
}, ]

function hasValue(obj, key, value) {

  if (obj[key].indexOf(value) > -1) {
    return true;
  }
}

function filterArray(carray) {
  var arr = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i <= carray.length; i++) {

    if (hasValue(carray[i], "systemId", "System A") &&
      hasValue(carray[i], "fieldStr", "Str B")) {

      arr.push(carray[i].id);
      console.log(carray[i].id);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

hasValue(CoilArray[0], "fieldStr", "Str A");

filterArray(CoilArray);
```

Comment: Obviously you can do what you like in your own code, but when sharing code with others (for instance, asking for help), please take the time to indent and format your code in a readable, consistent way. (It's a good idea even when not sharing code with others, too.) (I've taken the code, run it through http://jsbeautifier.org [no affiliation], and removed extraneous blank lines for you on this occasion. [Ah, but now Fran's undone that, but done something similar.])

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i<= carray.length; i++){` You are going one past the end of the array.

Comment: Was formatting the code and question at the same time, I must have hit save just after you. Sorry @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Fran: No worries, we were doing much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can trim all that down to this. And the check to see if the systemId is an array I referenced this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

```
var filteredArray = CoilArray.filter(function (obj) {
  let isSystemA = false;
  let isStrB = false;

  // If Array then check if Array has value
  if (obj.systemId.constructor == Array) {
      isSystemA = obj.systemId.includes("System A") && isStrB;
  } else {
      isSystemA = obj.systemId === "System A";
  }

  if (obj.fieldStr.constructor == Array) {
      isStrB = obj.fieldStr.includes("Str B") && isStrB;
  } else {
      isStrB = obj.fieldStr === "Str B";
  }

  return isSystemA && isStrB;
});
```

This uses the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to solve via  `filter()` but it won't work for multiple object values of one key that are defined in `CoilArray` (e.g.  `fieldStr: ["Str B", "Str C"],`). It will only be able to filter the third object, since both keys I am looking for have only one value.
I believe my code above works, but I do not know why `obj` in `hasValue()` is statet as `undefined`. 
Can you help me with this?

Comment: @MaxGroh I'm gonna adjust my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop runs from 0 to `carray.length`. As a consequence, the last time `i` is called, it has a value of `carray.length`. And `carray[carray.length]` doesn't exist.

Just stop looping at `carray.length - 1` and your code works as expected.

#### Demo

```js
var CoilArray = [{
  id: "First Coil",
  systemId: ["System A", "System C"],
  fieldStr: ["Str A", "Str B"],
}, {
  id: "Second Coil",
  systemId: "System B",
  fieldStr: ["Str B", "Str C"],
}, {
  id: "Third Coil",
  systemId: "System C",
  fieldStr: "Str C",
}, ]

function hasValue(obj, key, value) {
  if (obj[key].indexOf(value) > -1) {
    return true;
  }
}

function filterArray(carray) {
  var arr = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < carray.length; i++) {
    if (hasValue(carray[i], "systemId", "System A") && 
        hasValue(carray[i], "fieldStr", "Str B")) {
      arr.push(carray[i].id);
      console.log(carray[i].id);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

hasValue(CoilArray[0], "fieldStr", "Str A");

filterArray(CoilArray);
```