# JSON test for array

Tags: json, node.js

I'm using a node module that returns some data. The data will be returned in one of two ways:

**single record**

```
single = {"records[]":{"name":"record1", "notes":"abc"}}
```

**multiple records**

```
multiple = {"records[]":[{"name":"record1", "notes":"abc"},{"name":"record2", "notes":"xyz"}]}
```

If I call the following I can get the value from single records

```
single['records[]'].name // returns "record1"
```

for multiple records I would have to call like this

```
multiple['records[]'][0].name // returns "record1"
```

problem occurs when I get back a single record but treat it as multiple

```
single['records[]'][0].name // returns undefined
```

right now I test like this:

```
var data = nodemodule.getRecords();
if(data['records[]'){ //test if records are returned
    if(data['records[]'].length){ //test if 'records[]' has length
        // ... records has a length therefore multiple exist
        // ... for loop to loop through records[] and send data to function call
    } else {
        // .length was undefined therefore single records
        // single function call where I pass in records[] data
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to test for single vs multiple records given that I'm under the constraints of what the node module returns or am I missing some easier way?

Comment: looks good to me, if there's no other requirements - always better to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.isArray(obj)`

> **obj**
>      The object to be checked.
>
> **true** if the object is an Array; otherwise, **false**.

```
if(data['records[]']){
          if(Array.isArray(data['records[]'])){
            // console.log('multiple');
          }else{
            // console.log('single');
          }
        }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26633883/4777670
Read this it has some faster methods.