# how can I convert Object to Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
[ { id: '5b3a223296fb381a29cf6fd9',
number: 1,
name: 'Tablet White EliteBook  Revolve 810 G2',
dprice: '0',
image: '' } ]
```

This is a response from the angular application. When I checked for its type, it is giving result 'object'.

```
var savedCart = JSON.parse(req.body.cart);
```

When I am using this query, it is still an 'object'. 
How can I convert this to an array?

Comment: That is an array with 1 element that is an object.  `typeof new Array()` does return object, as that's what an array is.

Comment: its an array and arrays are objects. If you want to check if its an array use `Array.isArray(variable)`

Comment: This *is* an array. However, an array is also an object, so if you did `typeof savedCart` you'd get `object`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: `typeof []` === `"object"` use `Array.isArray([])`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: Then how you will maintain the key and value pair? I mean you can store only values or properties in the array!

Comment: How you wish to keep it in an array? Share expected output please

Comment: What do you want to do? I see that you are using JSON.parse() which expects a string as a parameter, but you already have the JSON object in the array. What is your final goal? What are you going to to with savedCart?

Comment: I want to use it in exact same way, that the response is. The issue here is when I am using array specific functions like reduce on this, it is giving a message that this isn't a function

Comment: This will get put on [Hold] if you do not specify exactly what you need. Such expected output, or the ideology. Refer to [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in JavaScript both objects and arrays have the *typeof* of `'object'`. In fact even the NULL value has the *typeof* of `'object'`, what makes things even worse. If you want to distinguish all those "wannabe-objects" existing in JS, you should use something like:

```
function smartTypeOf(x) {
    if (typeof x !== 'object') return typeof x;
    if (x === null) return 'null';
    if (Array.isArray(x)) return 'array';
    return 'object';
}
```

You may alternatively want to use *instanceof* instead, e.g.:

```
if (x instanceof Array) return 'array';
if (x instanceof Promise) return 'promise';
if (x instanceof YourCustomClassInstance) return 'yourcustomclassinstance'
```

By the way, if it ever happened that you have something being an object and want an array (it is not case here, thou!):

- If the object is iterable, e.g. a `Set`, or an `arguments` instance:

  ```
  var x = new Set([1, 2, 1]);
  Array.from(x); // [1, 2]
  ```
- If the object is any (non-NULL) object and you want array of its properties **values** or **keys** respectively:

  ```
  var x = {a: 2, b: 4, c: 7};
  Object.values(x); // [2, 4, 7]
  Object.keys(x); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
  ```