# How to tell if an object is a typed array?

Tags: javascript

Right now, I achieve it by

```
if (obj instanceof Uint8Array || obj instanceof Uint16Array || obj instanceof Uint32Array ......
```

Its a very long line.
I know that testing instanceof against the parent class of an object yields true so is there a parent class among those typed arrays? I tried TypedArray but according to chrome it doesn't exist.

Anyone know if there is a base class between the typed arrays? Or some other method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo At a glance, none of the answers on that page discuss distinguishing between [_typed_ arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) and [_normal_ arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), which is what is being asked for here.

Comment: Ops! you have right! I jump the typed array, do you have to try with a map? store all the possible type inside a map and make a get by type? you can get the name of the class with `myObj.constructor.name`

Comment: Comment rather than answer, because I don't know quite enough to get it working: According to MDN, [all TypedArrays inherit from a `TypedArray` prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#description), which has no global variable but you can get as `Object.prototypeOf(UInt8Array)`. If you can get the appropriate level of prototype from an instance, you can compare against that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TypedArray` prototype [does exist but is not exposed directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray). You can get it using `Object.getPrototypeOf` from any of its typed arry subclasses, like this:

```
>> const TypedArray = Object.getPrototypeOf(Uint8Array)
>> console.log((new Uint32Array()) instanceof TypedArray)
true
```

So with the above `const TypedArray` in scope, your check simply becomes:

```
if (obj instanceof TypedArray) { ... }
```

Comment: [It's in the ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-%typedarray%-intrinsic-object) so it's not going anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a very good solution but I think you can achieve the same kind of behavior using a hacky way. Actually, I don't like this kind of solution. I used `Uint8Array.__proto__`, I have no idea why the prototype of Uint arrays doesn't exist in chrome.

```
const uint8Array = new Uint8Array();
const uint16Array = new Uint16Array();
const uint32Array = new Uint32Array();

console.log(uint8Array instanceof Uint8Array.__proto__); //true
console.log(uint16Array instanceof Uint8Array.__proto__); //true
console.log(uint32Array instanceof Uint8Array.__proto__); //true
```

Edit:

```
const typedArrays = [new Uint8Array(), new Uint16Array(), new Uint32Array()];

const result = typedArrays.every(elem => elem instanceof Uint8Array.__proto__);

console.log(result);
```

So, you can check any typed array using `Uint8Array.__proto__`.

Edit 2:

```
const isTypedArray = (arg) => {
  return arg instanceof Uint8Array.__proto__;
};


console.log(isTypedArray(uint8Array));// true
console.log(isTypedArray(uint16Array));// true
console.log(isTypedArray(uint32Array));// true
```

Comment: This is still looking at the _individual types_ of typed array. I think the question is looking for a single line that will detect _all_ typed arrays.

Comment: @IMSoP Sorry, I'm not so fluent in English. So, I don't know how to explain it but I edited the answer with sample codes. If you understand what I'm saying, please edit my answer, so everyone can understand

Answer (score 0):

How about shorten it by checking if it not a normal array like this :

```
if (!(obj instanceof Array)) {
  // Do stuff with typed array
}
```

Comment: But then what if `obj` is `42`, or `new NotAnArrayAtAll()`?