# Common interface to object and array

Tags: typescript, interface

I wrote a Typescript function where my argument could be either a string's array or a raw object.

its prototype is:

```
export const myFunction = async (line: string[] | myCustomType, config: any): Promise<String> => {
  if (line?.length < 2)
    //line is a string[]
  else
    //line is a mysCustomType
}
```

Where `myCustomType` is a raw object with a lot of properties / method.

In JavaScript I would have just tried to access to `line?.length` and if it would have been `undefined` I would have treated `line` like an instance of `myCustomType` (because `myCustomType` doesn't have `length` properties.

an array being an object, I already created a method in the Object class allowing me to directly differences the two type:

```
declare global {
  interface Object {
    isCustom(): boolean;
  }
}

Object.prototype.isCustom = function () {
  return false;
};
```

Where the method `isCustom` already exist in type `myCustomType` and doesn't return `false`. So I can differencies `line`'s type, but the typescript doesn't allow me to compile.

```
Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string[] | myCustomType'.
  Property 'length' does not exist on type 'myCustomType'
```

Shall I declare `line`'s type to be of `Object` and use my `isCustom()` method ? or is it uggly ?

Any ideas to get rid of this problem ?

Comment: [If you want to differentiate between array and object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript), why not just use `Array.isArray(line)`? Why do you have to change the built-in prototype of all objects everywhere?

Comment: Because even with the `Array.isArray(line)`, Typescript wouldn't allow me to compile !

Comment: please post more of your code then.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me:[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLYE8DCBXAzmAe1QBV0AHFAbwFgAoZB5YXHfIgLmQAoBKZAXgB8yMFGwQA3HUbIYBAp3xRQAcym0AvnWkICIfGnQAxbCARhgegcji50Z7gBtQERaNUBtALrIAPodZCEnIIABpkXRAYYBVOOBB0Hk4ABSgiZggAHgBldxAVYSFkGnoZYBhuAEEoKDh0ADpmatr0LmcQCB4+EpleqAgwbCgQZHaIeoArAlAuACJw2Z4JZAB6FbgaupECZCVVaRkNZAhHXCoD3oZ+weHRl3q5AmW15AmJvDAbXbyVC4YtTRAA)

Comment: Wait `if (line?.length < 2)` doesn't mean what you claim. If the length is 1, then you'd go into the `else` and you'd expect *the string with one character* to be `myCustomType`. TS is very correctly warning you here, why do you not want to use proper logic instead?

Comment: It was just an example to show you the `.length` method who'll works fine in JS willn't compile in TS, so what is the proper logic in this situation ? that's my question !

Comment: The proper logic, according to me, is to *not* pollute built-ins and to instead use a proper type guard. However, you say it "doesn't work" which I can't really believe. Nor can I really help, since you're now asking me to somehow give you a solution for code I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

The proper logic is

```
var isStringArray = false;
if (Array.isArray(line)) {
    isStringArray = true;
    line.forEach(function(item) {
        if (typeof item !== "string") {
            isStringArray = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Explanation: you need to check whether your variable is an array and then whether all its members are strings. Your way of checking for the value of `length` and validating based on that is incorrect even in principle, because your custom object may have a `length` member even if it's not an array. Also, in practice, your string array could have a `length` of 1 or 0 as well and it would be a string array even then.