# React/Redux with hooks to fetch from Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redux, react-hooks, use-effect, dispatch-async

I am trying to use redux and hooks with my rails / react application and running into a weird problem. When I first console log my list object that is being fetched, they display fine in the console and render correctly
[See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDCq9.png)

Here is my code for my Lists.js

```
 export default function Lists() {
  const lists = useSelector(state => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchLists())
  }, [])

console.log(lists)

      return (
      <div>
        <h2>Your Lists</h2>
        {lists && lists.map(list => {
          return <List list={list} key={list.id}/>
        })}
      </div>
      )
}
```

Then as soon as I write something else or refresh the page I am getting this error that map is not defined - even though clearly lists is an array of objects that should be able to be mapped over. [See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GneF.png)

Here is my reducer:

```
import { GET_LISTS } from "../constants"

export default function listReducer(state = {lists: []}, action){
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_LISTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                lists: action.payload
            }

        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

and my action:

```
export function fetchLists(){
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/lists")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((lists) => dispatch({ type: GET_LISTS, payload: lists }));
```

}
}

So basically when I comment out the code with  .map lists gets console.logged correctly, then I comment it in it renders the lists fine, and as soon I as I refresh the page I am getting this errer. Very confusing and I have no idea what else to try.

So far I have tried:

- adding fetchLists as a dependency to useEffect
- only dispatching in my action and just calling the function in useEffect
- putting the entire fetch request inside the useEffect instead of using an action creator

Basically no matter what I try I am still getting the

```
Lists.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: lists.map is not a function
```

error on a refresh.

It also puts me in a debugger when there is no debuggers in my app. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you try to `map()` an object rather than an array. See short example of the problem here:
[image]
When all is set, you probably use the initial value as array. that's why it works `[]`. But when you update the variable `lists` becomes an object `{[]}`, which is unmappable.
You could check if the `lists` not only exists, but also is the type you want it to be. Here are some answers for the checking process: [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript).

Here is the sandbox to reproduce the error you have and handle it without exception appearing using conditional rendering of the DOM:
[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bouman-4mv24c?file=/src/App.js)
Sample code to check if the type is array with `useEffect()`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("is array type? : ", Array.isArray(lists));
}, [lists]);
```

Comment: How do I implememnt this? I tried something like :  
  const checkLists = () => {
    if(lists && lists.constructor === Array ){
        lists.map(list => {
          return <List list={list}  key={list.id}/>
      })
  }
but I am not getting "Functions are not valid as a React child." error. is there a better way to check this?

      return (
      <div>
        <h2>Your Lists</h2>
        {checkLists}
      </div>
      )

Comment: @JessPesale here is the code, please check it https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bouman-4mv24c?file=/src/App.js