# Getting the array name and values in Javacript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My JSON output is similar to this below object and we have an array values as showing below

```
const object1 = {
  "sublists": {
    "item": [{
        "line": "1",
        "amount": "1200.00",
        "id": "227",
        "item": "227",
        "item_display": "5800520002800",
        "quantity": "1"
      }
    ],
    "shipping": [{
        "line": "1",
        "amount": "1200.00",
        "id": "227",
        "quantity": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to get the name of arrays and values in separate variable as showing below

Array name :item, line:  , 1
Array name :item , amount : 1200
Array name :item, id : 227
and so on ...
the array properties can varry depending on the json ouput  , im looking for a dynamic script in which i could access the array name and properties

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: Arrays are instanceof Object, and in that case you aren't outputting `k` anywhere.

Comment: Do you really need recursion? Can't you just use `for in` `object1.sublists` ?

Comment: i want to access dynamically and get the name of array and values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function iterateObject(obj, parent) {
  if (typeof obj == "object")
    if (!Array.isArray(obj))
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((prop) => {
        if (typeof obj[prop] == "object") iterateObject(obj[prop], prop);
        else console.log(`Parent name : ${parent},  ${prop} : ${obj[prop]}`);
      });
    else
      obj.forEach((elem) => {
        iterateObject(elem, parent);
      });
  else console.log(`Parent name : ${parent},  ${parent} : ${obj}`);
}


iterateObject(object1,"sublists");
```

UPDATE

this is code for your json in comment

```
iterateObject(object01,"item");
```

Comment: this is i was trying to do , thank you very much @Serge  , this second solution is dynamic and working perfect

Comment: Hi Serge , how i can access object within an array , its a same json as showing above but one more array is added into the item array e.g { "item": [ { "line": "1", "amount": "1700.00", "id": "227", "item": "227", "address": { "zip":"4001" , "country": "US" }, "tran_date": "01/01/2022", "quantity": "1" } ] }

Comment: @skyniazi I updated my answer. This code should be working for both

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will solve your problem. I followed the recursive nature of the code you gave and adapted it to make sure it was giving the output you desired. If you have any questions please let me know, and I'll try to address them.

```
function printValues(obj) {
  for (const [objKey, objValue] of Object.entries(
    obj
  )) {
    if (
      typeof objValue === 'object' &&
      !objValue.length
    ) {
      printValues(objValue);
    } else if (
      objValue !== undefined &&
      objValue.length > 0
    ) {
      for (let i = 0; i < objValue.length; i++) {
        const currentObject = objValue[i];

        let str = '';
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(
          currentObject
        )) {
          str += `Array name: ${objKey} , key1: ${key} , value: ${value}\n`;
        }

        console.log(str);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but this is restricted to two array properties ,array properties can varry depending on the result  e.g this is real json output   "sublists": {
        "item": [
            {            
                "line": "1",
                "amount": "1200.00",
                "id": "227",
                "item": "227",
                "item_display": "5800520002800",
                "quantity": "1"
            }
            
        ] 
        }  , i want it to be access dynamically , in this case output will be data , line , 1

Comment: I've adjusted my answer. Let me know if you need any additional modifications or clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to achieve the desired outcome is to pass the 'parentKey' to the recursive call:

```js
const object1 = {sublists: {sales_order: [], data: [{"key1": "a", "value": 2 }, {"key1": "b", "value": 4 }], memo: [{"key1": "a", "value": 5 }] } };

function printValues(obj, parentName = null) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
        obj.forEach(o => console.log(`Array name: ${parentName}. Key1: ${o.key1}. Value: ${o.value}`));
    } else {
        for (let k in obj) {
            printValues(obj[k], k);
        }
    }  
};

printValues(object1) ;
```

---

- The first `if` statement if to check if the varaible is an array or object. Logic taken from:
  [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

---

```
Array name: data. Key1: a. Value: 2
Array name: data. Key1: b. Value: 4
Array name: memo. Key1: a. Value: 5
```