# Typescript array being passed as object, testing with typeof operator

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is a dumb question but I have a function that does:

```
export function parseSomething(someList: string[]): string[] {
    someList.forEach((someField: string) => {
        console.log(typeof someField)
    })
```

`someField` is being read as an `object`. Why? The object being passed to this function is a string array.

Comment: You must be passing it an an array of objects. something like `parseSomething([{},{}] as any)`. Log it, scan your codebase for invocations, make sure they seem typed correctly etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand. It does work on execution time, so there is no TypeScript at this point. And there is no array type in JavaScript, as arrays are objects. You can read on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) for more about JavaScript types.

[Arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) exist only while writing code with your linter and on compilation time with your compilator as it's a TypeScript only type. You can use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to test if `someField` is an array on execution time, like so as an example:

```
console.log(Array.isArray(someField))
```

It's to know that there is a [typeof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) specific to TypeScript that's different from the above one, that can be used in type definition, like so:

```
let s = "hello";
let n: typeof s;
```

Comment: Hmm I don't think this answers the question. Additionally, I expect a strongly typed language to either throw an exception when an incorrect type is passed but for some reason that doesn't happen here

Comment: Yeah but that's how JavaScript is, and why we need TypeScript. And even combined, they are not a dynamically typed language.

Comment: @AviJain this 100% answers the question. You can [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/jr4932mx/) that calling typeof on an array will return `object`. Also, JavaScript is not a strongly typed language (which a big reason why typescript is a thing). As @yousoumar also stated, typescript does not exist at runtime and therefore doesn't throw any exceptions. You can find more information about what typescript is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html)