# pass array to backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, casting

Here i am trying to pass array to my backend (Node.js/Express). I want to change my type of "arr" to Array but its showing the "objects". I tried Object.enteries/keys/values but couldn't able to change it.

```
const K_Way_Merge_Sort = async ({
    array,
    setArray,
    setColorsArray,
    visualizationSpeed,
} = {}) => {
    var JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
    axios.post(
        'http://localhost:5000/k_way_external_merge_sort',
        {JSONObject}
        , ((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        }))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}

export default K_Way_Merge_Sort
```

My Backend File is

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const fs = require('fs')
const { readFileSync, promises: fsPromises } = require('fs');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,       
    optionSuccessStatus: 200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

function WriteFiles(array){
    var file = fs.createWriteStream('text/input.txt');
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        file.write(array[i] + '\n')
    }
    file.end();
}

app.post('/k_way_external_merge_sort',(req,res) => {
    let array = req.body.JSONObject;
    const arr = Object.values(array);
    res.send('done');
})

app.listen(5000,() => {
    console.log('running');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, typeof an array instance is actually an 'object'. If you so want, you can still test if it's an array with `arrayInstance instanceof Array`, or you might want to consider `Array.isArray()` method; other possiblities are mentionned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript).