# Handle Error With Axios Async/Await in React

Tags: reactjs, http, error-handling, axios

I'm using Axios to fetch some data:

```
export const getProducts = async () => {
   try {
       const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products`)
       return data
   } catch (err) {
       console.log(err)
       return err
   } 
}
```

Everything is fine, but I need to catch http errors inside try block. For example, when connection with the server is lost, Axios returns an AxiosError object:

> 1. AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request:
>    XMLHttpRequest, …}
> 2. code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
> 3. config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0,
>    …}
> 4. message: "Request failed with status code 404"
> 5. name: "AxiosError"
> 6. request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload,
>    …}
> 7. response: {data: '\n\n\n<meta char…re>Cannot GET
>    /api/prducts\n\n\n', status: 404, statusText: 'Not
>    Found', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
> 8. stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle
>    (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12)\n
>    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend
>    (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:117:66)"
> 9. [[Prototype]]: Error

The problem is: I want to render a div saying "There was an error fetching the data" if there is an error. If not, render a table with products as usual.

I call my function like this:

```
const productsArr = await getProducts()
```

How can I recognize if productsArr is a valid product array, or an AxiosError?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the official docs how to handle errors: https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

To see the error if no response was received (copied from the axios docs)

```
else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
```

You can wrap your component with an error-handling boundary. You can either create your component which will wrap your other component in which the error occurs using the `componentDidCatch` lifecycle method, which is the same as using `catch{}` inside try-catch https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidcatch. Or use a popular npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary

Answer (score 0):

I used this structure for fetching:

```
export const getProducts = async () => {
```

try {
const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products`)
return data
} catch (err) {
console.log(err)
return err
}
}

I deleted the return in the catch block. So if an error happens, it returns undefined.

I imported getProducts to my component. I did the fetching like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
        const productsArr = await getProducts()
        if (productsArr) {
            setProducts(productsArr)
            setLoading(false)
        } else {
            setLoading(false)
            setError(true)
        }
    })()
}, [])
```

So, I use conditional to validate if productsArr exist. If there was an error, since the fetching returns undefined, I activate setError(true).

It is not the best solution, because I lose access to the error data. I hope there is a better solution.